# How do I strip valid XML from file that contains excess data and junk

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have tried parsing with regex but not all XML files are being parsed!!

Tag names are not predefined which means, solution should identify the start and end of XML tag it self

Sample data goes like this:

```
<XML data> 
Random text 
<XML data> 
Random text
```

Comment: Are you saying that you have a file that contains a mix of XML and non-XML data?

Comment: @Dweeberly yup and non XML data contains some unsupported characters etc should be excluded

Comment: That is a hard problem unless you can find a way to filter the non-XML data, or you can assure that the non-XML data doesn't contain anything of the form <tag> </tag>.  Otherwise, the ambiguities will likely require some sort of manual intervention.

Comment: Non XML data does not contain any <tag></tag> forms. will it help to parse or strip the XML data out!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments this is a hard problem, especially without any knowledge of your data.  There could be a lot of edge cases.

The code below may work for what you want.  It attempts to find elements ('<element ...' or '<element/>', then determine the XML content by finding the end tag.  It checks this by trying to parse the XML and if that false it rejects the XML.

This code was written for clarity, not performance or good structure (it's all mainline fall-thru).  This should give you an example you can use as a good starting point for the type of parsing you described.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace messyXml {
class Program {

    const String almostXml = @"
@#$%random junk
<Fruits>
  <Apples>
    Pies
  </Apples>
  <Pears>
    Tarts
  </Pears>
</Fruits>
This is some junk about Fruits like Apples and Pears 
which can be made into Pies and Tarts.  I think that
Pears<Apples.  Edge case might be <Parts or /Apples>
<Parts No='123'>
  Pie Plate
</Parts>";

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Extracting XML from:");
        Console.WriteLine(almostXml);
        Console.WriteLine();
        int i = 0;
        var validXml = new StringBuilder();
        while (i < almostXml.Length) {
            if (almostXml[i] == '<') { // might be an xml start
                int ix = almostXml.IndexOfAny(" >\t".ToArray(), i + 1); 
                // this only check for space, > and tab, you may want to
                // include other whitespace chars

                if (ix < 0) {
                    ix = almostXml.IndexOf("/>", i + 1); // you might have <element/>
                    if (ix >= 0) {
                        // you could check if element name is valid
                        var xml = almostXml.Substring(i, (ix + 2) - i);
                        try {
                            // see if this is really xml
                            var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                            validXml.AppendLine(xml);
                            i = ix + 2;
                            continue; // next iteration of while i 
                            }
                        catch (System.Xml.XmlException) {
                            // do nothing
                            }
                        }
                    ix = almostXml.IndexOf(">", i + 1); // you might have <element/>
                    }
                else { // we found something like <element ...
                    var ix2 = almostXml.IndexOf('>', ix); // where is the '>'
                    if (ix2 >= 0) {
                        // build an end tag
                        var endtag = "</" + almostXml.Substring(i + 1, (ix - i) - 1) + ">";
                        var endix = almostXml.IndexOf(endtag, ix2);
                        if (endix >= 0) {
                            var xml = almostXml.Substring(i, (endix + endtag.Length) - i);
                            try {
                                // see if this is really xml
                                var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                                validXml.AppendLine(xml);
                                i = (endix + endtag.Length);
                                continue; // next iteration of while i
                                }
                            catch (System.Xml.XmlException) {
                                // do nothing
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            i++;
            }
        Console.WriteLine("-----------");
        Console.WriteLine("Valid XML found:");
        Console.WriteLine(validXml.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```